# How to create a drop-down list of geoprocessing tasks?

Tags: arcgis-server, javascript, geoprocessing, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, arcgis-rest-api

I need to construct a drop down menu with each choice enabling a different geoprocessing task to run over my script.

```html
<select id="myList" onchange="environment()">
   <option>Select..</option>
   <option value="http://********/arcgis/rest/services/EDDM/selectZIP/GPServer">DEV</option>
   <option value="http://********/arcgis/rest/services/EDDM/selectZIP/GPServer">SIT</option>  
   <option value="http://********/arcgis/rest/services/EDDM/selectZIP/GPServer">CAT</option>
   <option value="http://********/arcgis/rest/services/EDDM/selectZIP/GPServer">PROD</option>
</select>
```

They each run the same process albeit at different levels of production. I have this code that is a placeholder and uses just one value.

```js
function selectZIP(Zip_code){
    gp = new esri.tasks.Geoprocessor("http://********/arcgis/rest/services/EDDM/selectZIP/GPServer/selectZIP");
```

How can I make a drop-down that will allow the user to select which GPServer they need and use it on the same script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Working under the assumption you are using the latest ArcGIS JS API (3.5) with Dojo 1.8, you could use dojo/on and dojo/query to listen to the "change" event of the element.

```
require(['dojo/on', 'dojo/query'], function(on, query) {
    on(query('#myList'), 'change', function(e){
        var gpURL = e.target.value;
        console.log('list changed', gpURL);
        // call gp service with gpURL value
    });
});
```

You can then use the result of the e.target.value, which would be the URL in the dropdown to send to your Geoprocessor.

Comment: `function selectZIP(Zip_code){
    gp = new esri.tasks.Geoprocessor(gpURL);}`

So i would in turn make it like this?

Comment: You have a couple of options. You could do it like that, creating a new Geoprocessor task with every dropdown change or create the Geoprocessor ahead of time and just change the URL each time and run your task. The docs don't say the URL is read-only. https://developers.arcgis.com/en/javascript/jsapi/geoprocessor-amd.html

Comment: I've tried what you posted above and it returns a "TypeError: this._url is undefined" In the console it logs the url for each option in my drop down as I change it so i've gotten that far.

Comment: That probably means the Geoprocessor needs to has a URL in the constructor, so to get it working, I would use the method you listed above and create a new GP on every dropdown, get the functionality working then tweak it later if need be.

Comment: So what youre saying is i need 4 different `gp = new esri.tasks.Geoprocessor("http://eddmapi-dev.usps.gov/arcgis/rest/services/EDDM/selectZIP/GPServer/selectZIP");` with the URL changed. Do i use some sort of if/else statement? First time working with this

Comment: removing the "var" from infront of "gpURL" allowed me to plug it into the GP construction. Thanks for the helping hand